# How to improve my maxscript random blood generation code?

Tags: rendering, 3dsmax

The idea was simple. Draw basic blood drop meshes. Shuffle them with random generator to get final drop's. Export and render them in game as other meshes.

The problem is that it's not looks like a blood drop, but a rocks.

What is the best way to improve this? Redraw basic drops? Apply some modifier to final drop mesh? But what modifier? How to smooth borders in final drop mesh? I am totally stuck with this. The improvment must be codeable in MAXSCRIPT, not a manual correction of mesh, because I am a programmer not 3D modeller.

The generator final result screenshot.
[image]

Final blood drop:

[image]

P.S. For those who would like to test generator manually here it goes the [prooflink.](https://mega.co.nz/#!8hsXgLgB!Elca4CaSRkMp2ZtC3Q2RRBe9OF5k8QanZ2yAkL5crEg) Works nice at 2010 version.

Comment: I don't know how to implement this in maxscript, but it should be totally doable to use particles with metaballs, that is likely to give much more fluid-like properties to the mesh.